# How to evaluate " (num1+ num2) < num 3 " expression in boolean format?

Tags: java, regex

I need to evaluate " `(num1+ num2) < num 3` " expression in boolean format
Example :

```
String str = "(24+3) < 4";
```

Have to evaluate above `str` to `Boolean` if `true` or `false` and then use the final `Boolean` value inside `if ()` condition.

I do not want to extract individual characters, convert into `int`  and then keep evaluating each sub expressions.

Comment: then how do you expect to solve this? "24" and 24 have completely different meanings and values. you can't run numeric comparisons on Strings and expect the JVM to know what you want with it.

Comment: Already  discussed  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java

Answer (score 3):

You can use the javascript engine but I think it's too much for this:

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String str = "(24+3) < 4";
try {
    if (engine.eval(str)){
        ...
    }
} catch (ScriptException e) {
}
```

Comment: It *is* the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

And there's also a BeanShell (http://www.beanshell.org/):

```
    final Interpreter i = new Interpreter();

    try {
        Object res = i.eval("(24 + 3) < 4");
        System.out.println("Result is " + res);
    } catch (EvalError ex) {
        System.err.println("Error while evaluating expression: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```